# What is wrong in my code logically?

Tags: java, file-rename

I am working on a code to rename number of files in java. I have a list of the files in a `.txt`. File in which my program retreives the name of the document and its new name. It currently does not work.. It compiles and run but it wont rename my files.

Here's my code:

```
public static void rename(String ol, String ne){
  File oldfile =new File(ol);
  File newfile =new File(ne);
  int t=0;
  if( oldfile.isFile() && oldfile.canRead()){
     if (newfile.exists()){
        t++;
        ne = ne.substring(0,ne.lastIndexOf('.')) + " (" + t + ")" + 
           ne.substring(ne.lastIndexOf('.')) ;
        rename(ol,ne);
     }

     if(oldfile.renameTo(newfile))
        System.out.println("Rename succesful");
     else
        System.out.println("Rename failed" + " - " + ol + " " + ne);

  }else 
     System.out.println("CANNOT Rename " + oldfile + " because read/write issues. Check 
                          if  File exists" );
}     

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{   
    ReadFile ren = new ReadFile("List of Founds.txt");
    String r[] = ren.OpenFile();

    for(int j=0; j<ReadFile.numberOfLines; j++){

        String pdfOldName = r[j].substring(0,r[j].lastIndexOf('.'));
        String pdfNewName = r[j].substring((r[j].lastIndexOf('.') + 4));

        rename(pdfOldName, pdfNewName);
    } 
}
```

This is the 'List of founds' `.txt` file, the old name is on the left and the new name is on the right.

> test.pdf.txt ayo1
>
> test2.pdf.txt ayo2
>
> test3.pdf.txt ayo3

Comment: Can you post the output of what happens when your program runs?

Comment: it keeps the me 'rename failed'. thats the else part of line 6...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [File.html#renameTo(java.io.File)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29) to accomplish this.

Heres a quick sample program i wrote.
hope this puts you in right direction

```
public class FileMain {

    static int i = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file1 = new File("D:/workspace/dir");  
        renamefiles(file1);
    }

    private static void renamefiles(File file){

            File files[] = file.listFiles();
            for(File tempFile :files){

                if(tempFile.isDirectory()){
                    renamefiles(tempFile);
                }else{
                    System.out.println(tempFile.getName());

                    File renameFile = new File("sample-"+(++i)+".bck");
                    tempFile.renameTo(renameFile);

                }
            }



    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sudhakar, your code works wonders. I ll try to modify it to suite my needs. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You need a !

```
if (newfile.exists())
```

to

```
if (!newfile.exists())
```

You also need to [follow conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).  And [Unit Test](http://junit.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thanks for your response Will, but changing the condition newfile.exists() to !newfile.exists() didnt solve the problem.